# PIL only produces top row in a grid

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I've created a simple program to make a grid of images in PIL, but it only generates the top row and nothing else, here's my code:

```
def create_grid(im2,w,h):
     image = Image.new("RGBA",(2000,1000),(0,0,0))
     x = 0
     y = 0
     x_change = int(2000/w)
     y_change = int(1000/h)
     while y<1000:
             while x<2000:
                     image.paste(im2,(x,y))
                     x += x_change
             y += y_change
     image.show()
```

`im2` in this case is 100x100 and I'm calling `create_grid(im2,20,10)`. Why is only the top row appearing?

Comment: What is `im2.size` and `im2.mode`?

Comment: 100x100 and RGBA

Comment: The inner `while` loop can only run once - after that, `x` starts out over 2000, so it will never be entered again.  You simply need to reset `x` somewhere in the outer loop.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing reseting the `x` coordinate when changing from the first row to the second. So, the following images are all placed outside of the viewable area, with a value for x that is greater than 2000. Or rather, the `while` condition for `x` will not be met again: no other images are even attempted to be placed.

Just add an `x = 0` line:

```
def create_grid(im2,w,h):
     image = Image.new("RGBA",(2000,1000),(0,0,0))
     x = 0
     y = 0
     x_change = int(2000/w)
     y_change = int(1000/h)
     while y<1000:
             while x<2000:
                     image.paste(im2,(x,y))
                     x += x_change
             y += y_change
             x = 0
     image.show()
```